# How to detect (in js) if files are selected in HTML5 multiple input?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, onchange, html-input

I googled it and found out that i can listen the onchange event on input type="file". But this works only with input without the multiple attribute. Does anyone know how to listen "files selected" event and fire a function after user has selected the files?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="file" multiple name="files" />
```

and in jquery:

```
$("input[type='file']").on("change", function(){
   var files = $(this).prop("files");  // you'll get selected file(s)

   console.log(files);  // here will display files as objects with their properties. Check with Chrome console what properties are.
});
```

if `files` is undefined then the browser must support HTML5.